# Modifiying a server securely

Tags: linux, ssh, security, ssl, root

I wanted to purchase a dedicated server to host my site. I am a newcomer to this and wanted to know if I hired someone to secure the server and SSH for me, will that put me at risk? Or is there an account I can give them with permissions to do those things? Again, I am new at this and don't want an insecure linux server.

Answer (score 4):

Almost anything puts you at risk.  You just need to decide what level of risk is acceptable to you.  In this case, the risks of hiring someone are potentially:

- They might have inflated their credentials and not be as good at the work as they say they are.
- They might be dishonest and make unauthorized changes to your system.  (This is much less common than the previous point.)

The risks of not hiring someone to secure your server are potentially:

- You might not have the experience to do a good job of securing your server and might overlook something.

As for "Or is their a account I can give them with permissions to do those things?" they will need to have enough permission to just about anything they want to your system.

Based on your closing line, "again am new at this and don't want a insecure linux server," I think it's safe to say that you want to hire someone.  As womble suggested, make sure that the person you hire is qualified and trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hiring someone to work on your server puts you at risk.  However, any time you hire anyone to do *anything* for you, there's a risk.  The important thing is to ensure that the person you hire is trustworthy, experienced, and able to do the job you've hired them for.